# Disable/enable UIBarButtonItem base on UITextView content swift

Tags: swift, uitextview, uitoolbar

I'm trying to grey out a UIBarButtonItem when the TextView is empty, and enable it when the TextView isn't empty.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let newButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .compose, target: self, action: nil)
    toolbarItems = [newButton]
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

}
```

I have heard suggestion about implementing an observer or implementing a TextView delegate method. Can someone please provide a concrete example.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try my code.**

I used it for my project.

```
func textChanged(sender: NSNotification) {
    if emailTextField.hasText && passwordTextField.hasText {
        loginButton.isEnabled = true
        loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 139, g: 0, b: 139)
    } else {
        loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 139, g: 77, b: 139)
        loginButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

and add this to viewDidload:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(textChanged),name:NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidChange,object: nil)
loginButton.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: Thank you the observer method works great. I never really knew how observer works =]

Comment: Excellent solution! Well done... But use the viewWillAppear method instead of viewDidLoad. It's more sensitive than the viewDidLoad